# Modify child class from parent class with style class passed as props

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I need to modify the styles of the child component from the parent component. But the styles defined in the parent class are not getting reflected in the child component ? What can be the possible approach?

Component2 ( Child Component )

```
<div className={ classNames(css.class2, this.props.classWrapper) }>
    <div className={css.childclass2}></div>
</div>
```

Component1 (Parent Component)

```
<Component2 classWrapper={css.class1} />
```

```
.class1{
    .childclass2{
        // the styles defined here are not reflected in the Component2
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting the element in the debugger to verify that the class was there, and not used for some reason? Could be that your compiled sass didn't refresh upon load?

Comment: Yes, I did. React classes apparently doesn't work this way I guess. Eventually solved it using another className passed as props to the childClass